# Bash Trim Function

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to understand how the following bash script operates

```
trim_string() {
    # Usage: trim_string " example string "
    : "${1#"${1%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
    : "${_%"${_##*[![:space:]]}"}"
    printf '%s\n' "$_"
}
```

I think that : operates as a no-op but that is as far as I get.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see that $_ is explained here https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html

Answer (score 6):

`:` is indeed a no-op, in that it doesn't do anything, but it is still a command (it is equivalent to `true`). As such it still modifies shell variables that depend on the last run command, like the well known `$?` (return status of last command) or the less well known `$_` (last argument to the last command).

Here it is used to modify `$_`:

- the first use trims spaces to the left. It first gets all spaces to the left by removing all characters after the first non space character (`${1%%[![:space:]]*}`), then removes those spaces from the left of the variable and passes the result to `:` (doing nothing, but setting `$_` to the content of `$1` with spaces to the left removed)
- the second use trims spaces to the right using a similar technique (find all spaces to the right, then remove them)

The last line simply prints the resulting variable followed by a newline.